# Check to see if a column value exists prior to insert into SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jsoup

Using JSoup to parse HTML then insert rows into a MS SQL Server DB. To avoid duplicates, I need to check to see if the guid exists prior to insert execution. The code works except that I can't get a validation on the guid. See the Select statement within the insert block. Returns the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part
>   identifier "FeedMessage.guid" could not be bound.     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
>     at Archiver.Database.writer(Database.java:58)   at
>   RSS.Test.main(Test.java:35) Java Result: 1

```
    // Need to use this class for all of the DB-related interactions. 
    // Add methods to this class for added capabilities from within the GUI
package Archiver;

import RSS.FeedMessage;
import RSS.Test;
import Scraper.Scraping;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author joel.ramsey
 */
public class Database {

    Statement stmt;

    String DriverName;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://sss.ss.ss.ss:1433;databaseName=TextAnalytics";
    String DBuser = "xx";
    String DBpassword = "xxxxxx";

    //Method to connect to the DB upon initialization
    public void connectionText() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.DBuser, this.DBpassword);) {

            if (con != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) con.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception...");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    //Method to write the parsed content of the RSS source article to the DB.
    public void writer(String Title, String Description, String Link, String Author, String guid, String contents) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement writeStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.DBuser, this.DBpassword);
            writeStmt = con.prepareStatement("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TextAnalytics FROM Archive_Source WHERE guid = FeedMessage.guid) INSERT INTO Archive_Source(title,description,link,author,guid,contents) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            writeStmt.setString(1, Title);
            writeStmt.setString(2, Description);
            writeStmt.setString(3, Link);
            writeStmt.setString(4, Author);
            writeStmt.setString(5, guid);
            writeStmt.setString(6, contents);
            writeStmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(con, writeStmt, rs);
        }
    }

    //Method to close the connection manually. Called at the conclusion of each DB contact job.
    protected void close(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    //Method to delete all contents from the table. Should be called from the GUI
    public void delete(String Title, String Description, String Link, String Author, String guid, String contents) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement writeStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.DBuser, this.DBpassword);
            writeStmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE * FROM Archive_Source");
            writeStmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(con, writeStmt, rs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "FeedMessage"?  I don't see that table or table alias in your query.  I think you want to create another parameter with the same guid value, and specify that in the EXISTS subquery instead of "FeedMessage.guid".

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong in your SQL Statement. I've broken it into multiple lines so the answer is easier to read.

```
" IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TextAnalytics FROM Archive_Source " +
" WHERE guid = FeedMessage.guid) INSERT INTO " +
" Archive_Source(title,description,link,author,guid,contents) " +
" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)") "
```

1. What is `FeedMessage.guid`? If `FeedMessage` is a table, then it needs to be referenced in the `FROM` statement.
2. You are setting the values for the 6 `INSERT` Statement Parameters, but not for the `guid` function parameter. In the section where you say `WHERE guid = FeedMessage.guid`, shouldn't you parameterize that `guid` also, or concatenate the value like so. `"WHERE '" + guid + "'= FeedMessage.guid"`.

So if my assumptions on your code are correct, the code should be as follows.

```
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.DBuser, this.DBpassword);
        writeStmt = con.prepareStatement(
                         " IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TextAnalytics " +
                         " FROM Archive_Source WHERE guid = ?) " +
                         " INSERT INTO Archive_Source " +                                                          
                         " (title,description,link,author,guid,contents) " +
                         " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) )";
        writeStmt.setString(1, guid);
        writeStmt.setString(2, Title);
        writeStmt.setString(3, Description);
        writeStmt.setString(4, Link);
        writeStmt.setString(5, Author);
        writeStmt.setString(6, guid);
        writeStmt.setString(7, contents);
        writeStmt.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        close(con, writeStmt, rs);
    }
```

Notice I removed `FeedMessage.guid` and replaced it with the `guid` parameter and also assume that the left side of that comparison is a field called `guid` in your `Archive_Source` table.

Comment: FeedMessage is a Java class file where we are getting our guid value from the parsed HTML. I'm trying to see if it exists in the DB before inserting it.

Comment: Oh, then it should be outside the `"` quotes enclosing the select statement, and concatenated into it.